# Set UINavigationController's UITabBarItem inside a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm developing a iphone app that has a main viewcontroller(UITabBarController) with UINavigationControllers in each tab. The problem is that I can't change the TabBarItem's data(title and image).

This is how I load the viewcontrollers:

```
AroundViewController *aroundViewController = [[AroundViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aroundViewController];
[[navController navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, nil];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

[self presentViewController:tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I'm trying set the tabbaritem in the aroundviewcontroller's init, but I don't succeed.
I was reading and one solution was, in the init,

```
[self setTitle:@"whatever"];
```

This worked but I couldn't change the image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
In the viewWillAppear I put:

```
[[[self navigationController] tabBarItem] setTitle:@"HELLO"];
```

That works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the tabBarItem instance of your view controller to access the tab bar item directly!

```
[self.tabBarItem ....]

[self.tabBarItem setImage: ...]
[self.tabBarItem setTitle: ...]
```

EDIT:

hm, try the following then in your init or viewWillAppear method:

```
    UITabBarItem* tabBarItem =  [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"YourTitle" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"] tag:9];
    self.tabBarItem = tabBarItem;
    [tabBarItem release];
```

Comment: I tried in the aroundviewcontroller's init [[self tabBarItem] setTitle:@"Cerca"] and didn't work

Comment: However [self setTitle:@"Cerca"] works but I can't put that for the image

Comment: neither. neither in the init nor in the viewwillappear

Answer (score 1):

Before setting the UIViewControllers for the UITabBarController you can do this:

```
[navController.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MY-IMAGE"]];
[navController setTitle:@"MY-TITLE"];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, nil];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```